# Why modules imported with "as" in exec?

Tags: python-3.x

someone wrote a piece of code that executed by `exec()`. In given string some modules are imported but I couldn't find why they are imported with `as` prefix.
For example

```
    CODE_WRAPPER = '''
def main():
    from selenium import webdriver as __mock_webdriver
    import os as __mock_os
    import sys as __mock_sys
    import json
    import datetime
    import time
    import unittest
 
    def print(*args, sep=' ', end=''):
        __mock_sys.stdout.write(sep.join(args) + end)

    try:
        {user_code}
    except:
        //Do something
        raise
    else:
        //Do something else 
    finally:
        __mock_os.chdir(current_path)
        driver.quit()

main()
'''

    def _adjust_code(code, screenshot_path):

        format_dict = {        
            'user_code': '\n        '.join(code.splitlines()) or 'pass',
        }

        return CODE_WRAPPER.format(**format_dict)
        
   
    def _execute_code(code):
        code_output = StreamOutput()
        sys.stdout = code_output
        
        try:
            # Send globals and locals as {} for security issues
            exec(code, {}, {})
        except:
            if getattr(settings, 'DEBUG', False):
                raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
            else:
                # Limit exception deep for security
                raise Exception(traceback.format_exc(limit=0))
        else:
            output = code_output.get_value_list()
        finally:
            # restore stdout to default
            sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

        return output
```

So is there any reason why `os` module imported and used as `__mock_os`

Comment: Why not ask the person who wrote said code?

Comment: It's been written very long time. Its practically not possible. Besides, I see this approach other places as well and I didn't ask for code explanation of particular code, I asked reason of a way usage.

Answer (score 2):

```
import module as user_defined_name
```

A common use for this is to shorten a long module name making the code easier to read.